# when install OSMnx get erroe "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 24: invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, utf-8, installation

I have Python 3.6.1 32 bit,
OS windows 10 x64,

Tried install

pip install OSMnx

get error

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.**stdout**.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 24: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "C:\Users\liuzi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 24: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

The [OSMnx installation instructions](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx#installation) suggest using conda-forge to install. This is particularly important on Windows, as you want to avoid compiling all the C extensions required by the geospatial dependencies.

```
conda install -c conda-forge osmnx
```

Or if all else fails, do the install in a nice clean [virtual environment](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
conda create --yes -c conda-forge -n OSMNX python=3 osmnx
source activate OSMNX
```

That should solve any Windows-related install problems (and works for Mac and Linux too).